# google protobuf-js : How to parse efficiently my messages

Tags: javascript, angular, websocket, protocol-buffers

I'm working on an Angular5+ front-end which is using google-protobuf JS with a WebSocket to communicate with the backend.

I currently have 2 objects from my `.proto` files :

- a Request object.
- a Notification object.

I have then made a handler service that will get the messages sent through the WebSocket, but then I got a big issue : I cannot find a way to parse / deserialize efficiently my objects :

```
this._socketService.getSocket().onmessage = ((message: Message) => {
  const uiArray = new Uint8Array(message.data);
  this.parseMessage(uiArray);
});

parseMessage(uiArray: Uint8Array) {
  let response = null;

  // DOES NOT WORK
  // response = reqRep.Response.deserializeBinary(uiArray) || notif.BackendStatusNotification.deserializeBinary(uiArray);

  // <==== This is where I need to find a good way to deserialize efficiently my objects
  // TEMPORARY
  if (uiArray.byteLength === 56) {
    response = reqRep.Response.deserializeBinary(uiArray)
  } else {
    response = notif.BackendStatusNotification.deserializeBinary(uiArray);
  }

  // Notify different Observables which object has changed based on their type
  switch (response && response.hasSupplement() && response.getSupplement().array[0]) {
    case 'type.googleapis.com/req.BackendStatusResponse':
       this._responseSubject.next(response);
       break;
     case 'type.googleapis.com/notif.BackendStatusNotification':
       this._notificationSubject.next(response);
       break;
     default:
       console.log('DOESN\'T WORK');
   }
}
```

I tried using a `||` as shown in the code to always be able to deserialize my response but it doesn't work : if the first one fails, I get a runtime error.

I have a few insights and I though maybe someone could help me :

- Either I have to do `try` `catch` all around to manage every case (Which is the worst possible solution obviously).
- There is something I did wrong in the way I try to deserialize and it's a dumb mistake. I though maybe 
  I could use a generic `Message.deserialize()` from `google-protobuf`, but there is no way this work since each object should implement their own deserialize method.
- Or the last one, I should make a `.proto` file in which I set a base object that will nest all of my different objects for my application. This way I could deserialize a single type of message that will be able to deserialize the nested objects with it. (To me this is the best solution but it's quite costly for the backend)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I did the last option I mentionned in the question, which is to encapsulate all my different objects in a generic object.

This way, I have only one way to deserialize my objects which will then dispatch the processing of the nested known objects. It works flawlessly.

Comment: And it was also pretty fast to adapt the backend as well.